# C# Combox.text string always shows empty string within Timer tick function

Tags: c#

I have an application where combox text get populated with data, I have two timer function to read the combox text content, one timer works fine, but the other time always shows combox content is always empty string. I am wondering where things are wrong

```
private void AddNewDataToSystemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tbAddTrainTrainID.Text != "" && tbAddTrainRegionID.Text != "" && tbAddTrainSegmentID.Text != "")
        {
            bool isTrainAdded = CommonStore.TrainSimMainDatabase.AddNewTrainInToSystem(Convert.ToInt32(tbAddTrainTrainID.Text),
                Convert.ToByte(tbAddTrainRegionID.Text), Convert.ToByte(tbAddTrainSegmentID.Text));

            CommonStore.TrainSimMainDatabase.InitializingTrainCollection[Convert.ToInt32(tbAddTrainTrainID.Text)].VehicleList.IsManualTrain = false;

            if (isTrainAdded)
            {
                cbTrainList.Items.Add(tbAddTrainTrainID.Text);
                cbRemoveTrainID.Items.Add(tbAddTrainTrainID.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                TrainChangeRequestResponse.Text = "Train already exists in the system.";
            }
        }
    }


private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommonStore.TrainSimMainDatabase != null)
        {

            if (CommonStore.TrainSimMainDatabase.InitializingTrainCollection.Count > 0 && cbTrainList.Text != "")
            {
                // huge code
            }
}  

 }

public void VATCTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbTrainList.Text != "")
        {


\\ huge code
```

Comment: How do you know it's showing an empty string? In one case you are checking only the combobox, and in the other you're checking other values as well. It seems more likely that `Count` property is `<= 0`, or `TrainSimMainDatabase` is `null`.

Comment: I checked via debug method that, the content of cbTrainList.Text within Timer1_Tick is always not an empty string, but the same cbTrainList.Text is always empty string in VATCTimer_Tick. I even tried the using the same if condition of Timer1_Tick in VATCTimer_Tick. But still same results

Comment: For clarification, you are saying that Timer1_Tick is showing a different value for cbTrainList.Text than VATCTimer_Tick. Specifically, VATCTimer_Tick shows that cbTrainList.Text == "" where as Timer1_Tick shows that cbTrainList.Text != "". Is this correct?

Comment: yes that is correct, not sure what wrong. Ideally cbTrainList.Text should show the same value in both the timers one shows one doesnt